# Proto import from another project in Bazel

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

My directory structure is as follows:

```
├── proto
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── hello.proto
├── src
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── outer.proto
└── WORKSPACE
```

The `proto/hello.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package hello;
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
message HelloReply {
  string msg = 1;
}
```

The `proto/BUILD` file:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
proto_library(
    name = "hello_proto",
    srcs = ["hello.proto"],
)
```

The `src/outer.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "proto/hello.proto"; // What path to import from?
message OuterMessage {
  HelloRequest req = 1;
  HelloReply resp = 2;
}
```

The `src/BUILD` file:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
proto_library(
    name = "outer_proto",
    srcs = ["outer.proto"],
    deps = ["//proto:hello_proto"],
)
```

When I run `blaze build //src:outer_proto`, I get the following error:

```
src/outer.proto:6:3: "HelloRequest" is not defined.
src/outer.proto:7:3: "HelloReply" is not defined.
src/outer.proto:3:1: warning: Import proto/hello.proto is unused.
```

Why does it not work?

EDIT: Running blaze with debug options yielded more information, but I still don't understand it -

```
bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/protoc --direct_dependencies proto/hello.proto:src/outer.proto '--direct_dependencies_violation_msg=%s is imported, but //src:outer_proto doesn'\''t directly depend on a proto_library that '\''srcs'\'' it.' '--descriptor_set_out=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/src/outer_proto-descriptor-set.proto.bin' '-Isrc/outer.proto=src/outer.proto' '-Iproto/hello.proto=proto/hello.proto' src/outer.proto)
```

Comment: You're trying to import ```hello.proto``` from ```outer.proto``` with the line ```import "proto/hello.proto";```. But not able to find ```hello.proto``` at this location, Is it really correct?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation no, the import is clearly working. It gives a different error if the import is wrong. It is not working despite the import working.

Comment: Allow me to post an answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the `hello.proto` file in `outer.proto`. But, *Protobuf* doesn't support relative imports like C/C++ does. You'll either have to use the **WORKSPACE-relative** path to import `hello.proto` or, if that's not possible for some reason, add `strip_import_prefix` to the `proto_library` targets.

Modified `src/BUILD` file to include `strip_import_prefix`;

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
proto_library(
   name = "outer_proto",
   srcs = ["outer.proto"],
   deps = ["//proto:hello_proto"],
   strip_import_prefix = "src",
)
```

And in your `src/outer.proto` file, you should import `hello.proto` without the **<strike>proto/</strike>** prefix;

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "hello.proto";
message OuterMessage {
 HelloRequest req = 1;
 HelloReply resp = 2;
}
```

Here, I use `strip_import_prefix` attribute to strip a prefix from the import paths in the `.proto` files. In your case, it's set to "src", which means that Bazel will look for the `hello.proto` file in the **src directory**, not in the **<strike>proto directory</strike>**.

*The solution assumes that your **WORKSPACE** file is at the root of your project. If it's not, you might need to adjust the **strip_import_prefix** value accordingly.

Comment: This does not work. I get the error " .proto file 'src/outer.proto' is not under the specified strip prefix 'src/src'". Also I edited my original post, the eror seems to do with direct_dependencies_violation_msg. I am trying to figure out what that is.

Comment: The error message show because it can't find the **HelloRequest** and **HelloReply** messages in ```src/outer.proto```. This is likely because the import path in ```src/outer.proto``` is incorrect. As I mentioned in above, you should adjust the import statement in ```outer.proto``` to be the path from the root of your workspace to ```hello.proto```. This would look something like **import "//proto:hello.proto";**

Comment: I did exactly as your asked and it did not work as mentioned above. The more detailed error as I understand it gives error for the following "--direct_dependencies proto/hello.proto:src/outer.proto". Since "src/outer.proto" is marked as it's own dependency as is never used, it probably generates the error.